# IE11 changes zoom when switching between monitors

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to stop Internet Explorer changing zoom when switching between monitors?

I have a laptop and a secondary monitor. Both have screen resolutions of 1920x1080 although they are not physically the same size. When I drag an Internet Explorer window from one to the other it always "corrects" the zoom for me. I don't want it to this. Is there a way to make it stay at 100% regardless of the window in which it is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it by changing DPI settings.

1. Control Panel
2. Display
3. Select "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays"
4. Apply

IE should stop zooming when changing monitors.